# Authorization error in Onfido with same api token

Tags: api

I am using onfido v3.2 and I want to create SDK token. First I had create applicant using sandbox API key.

```
curl -X POST https://api.eu.onfido.com/v3.2/applicants/ \
  -H 'Authorization: Token token=<YOUR_API_TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}'
```

Then I had use applicant id from above api response for create SDK token and use same API token. https://documentation.onfido.com/#create-applicant

```
curl -X POST https://api.eu.onfido.com/v3.2/sdk_token \
  -H 'Authorization: Token token=<YOUR_API_TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
     "applicant_id": "<APPLICANT_ID>"
   }'
```

I am using same API TOKEN in both api but sdk create api return error.
https://documentation.onfido.com/#generate-sdk-token

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "authorization_error",
        "message": "Authorization error: please re-check your credentials",
        "fields": {}
    }
}
```

I don't understand what going wrong here? Thank you in advance.